# When should UV regulators be removed?

Tags: operators, renormalization, regularization, effective-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I have been working in QFT for a few years now, and I cannot believe I've never come across this problem. When considering an effective field theory, the allowed operators mix under renormalization:
$$
\mathcal{O}_i^{0}=Z_{ij}\mathcal{O}_j
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_i^{0}$ represents a bare operator $i$, $\mathcal{O}_i$ is its renormalized counterpart, and $Z_{ij}$ is a matrix of renormalization constants mixing all operators with a given set of quantum numbers. Of course, the "=" above must be treated in a weak sense, since the operator product expansion (OPE) is defined in the limit of spatially overlapping fields.

What I cannot figure out is the definition of "renormalized" in this setting. In particular, I'm not sure when the regulator should be removed. This usually doesn't matter, but when an operator shares the quantum numbers of the vacuum, there may be a divergence at leading order. For example, if we look at the renormalization of the scalar quark bilinear ($\mathcal{O}_S=\bar{\psi}\psi$), there are two operators to consider. These are the scalar itself and the vacuum (in this case, we essentially have the operator $\mathcal{O}_{m^3}=m^3$). The mixing equation then becomes
$$
\mathcal{O}_S^{0}=Z_{Sm^3}\mathcal{O}_{m^3}+Z_{SS}\mathcal{O}_{S}.
$$

Assuming we use dimensional regularization (DR) with $d=4-2\epsilon$, I see two potential problems with this equation. The first is the inconsistency in the canonical dimensions of the operators. In DR, the bare scalar density has dimension $d-1$, but the mass operator stays at dimension 3. Of course this can be taken care of by defining the vacuum with a factor of some scale $\mu^{-2\epsilon}$, but this seems to imply that the renormalized operators should be treated likewise. The alternative is that we simply define the renormalized operators explicitly as
$$
\mathcal{O}_i=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}Z^{-1}_{ij}\mathcal{O}_j^{0}.
$$
This seems to be consistent with Wilson and Zimmermann's original treatment of composite operators as an asymptotic expansion around coincidental spacetime arguments. In this sense, the locality of the product fields is identical to the continuum limit of a cutoff scheme.

This leads me to the second problem. When we have a mixing equation as above, we can extract the $Z$-factors order-by-order in the coupling with an appropriate choice of correlation functions. In the above case, $Z_{SS}$ is obtained by choosing a two-quark state. Similarly, $Z_{Sm^3}$ is found with a one-point vacuum function. Of course, this second correlator (let's call it $\Gamma_i$ for the $i^{th}$ operator) diverges at leading order, so the corresponding $Z$-factor has a pole at leading order. At the first subleading order, there is thus an ambiguity in defining the product $Z_{Sm^3}\Gamma_{m^3}$. If the renormalized correlator is not defined as the continuum limit of the bare quantity minus the pole, it is possible that the $1/\epsilon$ pole in $Z_{Sm^3}$ at leading order will multiply the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ terms in the correlation function, changing the finite part of the renormalized correlation function.

This certainly cannot be a choice of convention. The origin of the OPE and the Wilson-Zimmermann treatment leads me to believe that the renormalized quantities must be defined with the regulator already removed. This is further supported by the dimensional arguments above. In order that the dimensionality be consistent, the mixing equation
$$
\mathcal{O}_i^{0}=Z_{ij}\mathcal{O}_j
$$
must be interpreted as an equivalence relation, implicitly containing the limit (as above) on the renormalized quantity.

Is any of this correct? I've been searching for these details for nearly a month, but it seems that there are no clear treatments of this topic. My conclusion (and prior intuition) is that there should be no regulator present in a renormalized quantity by definition, but I can find no confirmation of this nor any precise definition of "renormalized" in this context. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can understand why this would be confusing. It is indeed true that the renormalized operators should be treated as the limit of the bare operators as the regulator is removed. This is because the bare operators depend on the regulator and are not physical quantities, whereas the renormalized operators are physical and should not depend on the regulator.